# Parsing A Complex, Multiline CSV File in C#

Tags: c#

I have searched the site, and found multiple examples for how to accomplish C# parsing using a variety of methods...but have found none that can help me in this specific scenario.  I have a complex CSV file that needs parsing.  Here is a sampling of some of the header data...

```
REPORT TITLE,New Query,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
REPORT DESCRIPTION,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
GENERATED,12/20/2019 7:33 AM ET,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Client Name,Client A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Time Frame,Last Completed Period,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Calendar year,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Received Date,Custom,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Service Date,Custom,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Adjustments,CHOICE(S),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Phone Calibration,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
View,N/A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
SERVICE LINE,Service Line Example A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
SITE,General 1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,General 2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,General 3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,General 4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,General 5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,General 7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
FILTER,CHOICE(S),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Client ID,'00001',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,'00002',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,'00003',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,'00004',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,'00005',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,'00006',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

There is NOTHING I can do about the formatting of the CSV file, as it is part of a legacy system.  The 40 commas placed at the end of each row, as well as those used as row separators, are placed by the system.

Here is where I am with my code so far...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourcePath = @"L:\sourceData.csv";
            var delimiter = ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,";
            var tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var lineNumber = 0;

            var splitExpression = new Regex(@"(" + delimiter + @")(,)(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)");

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempPath))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourcePath))

            {
                string line = null;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lineNumber++;

                    var rows = splitExpression.Split(line).Where(s => s != delimiter).ToArray();

                    // This is where I need to place the parsed data into objects

                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(delimiter, rows));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I need to move each parsed piece of data into its own defined object.  I have that class already built.

ANY help that can be provided would be considered a holiday miracle at this point!  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is currently written, it is a little difficult to see where you're stuck exactly. Please elaborate more on what your problem is and also have a look at [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: CSV format is simple ... there are lines - representing rows and delimiter (`,` in your case) which seperates columns ... what someone put in give row and column is not a parsing problem

Comment: You are the only one that knows the format of the csv being processed by your script. Look into using string.Split(',') and check first or second index of the resulting array to see if that gives you what you are looking for to determine the class it should go in

Comment: Post the class?  I woldn't use regex in tis case.  Instead : string[] row = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jdweng!  I do have a follow-up question, though.

Let's look at "Received Date".  In my class, I have three variables related to Received Date:  ReceivedDateLabel, ReceivedDateType, and ReceivedDateValue.  In my CSV file, ReceivedDateLabel and ReceivedDateType will ALWAYS be on the same line.  Your code example is helping me parse these into the class perfectly.  ReceivedDateValue, however, will always be on the next line in the file.  You can see the layout in my original post.  How do I move to the next line to use that value without messing up the row count?

Comment: Why do you care about the line count?  The line count is really the lines that do not start with a comma.  My code always put the lines starting with comma with the data in the previous row.  The date the items are in list and you get get the pieces by indexing the list.

Comment: I misspoke.  I don't care about the line count.  What I do care about, in regards to the Received Date, is that the actual date range (handled as a String) appears on the next line, and is preceded by a comma.  When processing the Received Date data in the CSV file, my code needs to know to to "grab" the ReceivedDateLabel ("Received Date"), the ReceivedDateType ("Custom"), and the ReceivedDateValue ("01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015").  Does that make sense?

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no difference between knowing that the data is on two lines and the number of items in the array.  They both indicate the same information.  You have to parse each item in the array from left to right to determine the type of data.  It is no different then knowing the data is on two lines.

Comment: OK.  I think I understand.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            Report report = new Report();
            string header = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                List<string> data = new List<string>();
                string[] row = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                if (row.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith(","))
                    {
                        data = row.ToList();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header = row[0];
                        data = row.Skip(1).ToList();
                    }
                    if (data.Count == 0) continue;

                    switch (header)
                    {
                        case "REPORT TITLE":
                            report.title = data[0];
                            break;
                        case "REPORT DESCRIPTION":
                            report.description = data[0];
                            break;
                        case "GENERATED":
                            report.generated = data[0];
                            break;
                        case "Client Name":
                            report.name = data[0];
                            break;
                        case "Time Frame":
                            if (report.timeFrame == null) report.timeFrame = new List<string>();
                            report.timeFrame.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "Received Date":
                            if (report.receivedDate == null) report.receivedDate = new List<string>();
                            report.receivedDate.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "Service Date":
                            if (report.serviceDate == null) report.serviceDate = new List<string>();
                            report.serviceDate.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "Adjustments":
                            if (report.adjustments == null) report.adjustments = new List<string>();
                            report.adjustments.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "View":
                            if (report.view == null) report.view = new List<string>();
                            report.view.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "SERVICE LINE":
                            if (report.serviceLine == null) report.serviceLine = new List<string>();
                            report.serviceLine.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "SITE":
                            if (report.site == null) report.site = new List<string>();
                            report.site.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "FILTER":
                            if (report.filter == null) report.filter = new List<string>();
                            report.filter.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                        case "Client ID":
                            if (report.clientId == null) report.clientId = new List<string>();
                            report.clientId.AddRange(data);
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public class Report
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string  generated { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<string> timeFrame { get; set; }
        public List<string> receivedDate { get; set; }
        public List<string> serviceDate { get; set; }
        public List<string> adjustments { get; set; }
        public List<string> view { get; set; }
        public List<string> serviceLine { get; set; }
        public List<string> site { get; set; }
        public List<string> filter { get; set; }
        public List<string> clientId { get; set; }
    }
}
```